# Spring Boot with Jersey as Servlet in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I try to deploy a simple Jersey application to my Tomcat-Server. But the Endpoint is not responding (404).

When I start this application as a Spring Boot application, everything works. But as a Servlet in Tomcat, the TestEndpoint is not working.

Servlet:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    }
}
```

I have 3 files:
JerseyConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.example");
        register(TestEndpoint.class);
    }
}
```

TestEndpoint:

```
@Component
@Path("/test")
public class TestEndpoint {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response test () {
        log.error("test");
        return Response.ok("test").build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Request:
As application: curl http://localhost:8080/test/test (works)
As servlet (api.war): http://localhost:8080/api/test/test (does not work)
Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your pom.xml

Comment: added to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is just a comment)Could you please update the question with the GET url you are trying?

Answer-
The problem was 
that the spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin in pom.xml was not removed. As per  https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

Comment: added to my question

Comment: You need to "comment out the declaration of the spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin in your pom.xml file". Please have a look at https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications and read the section "What about the Java EE Application Server?"